# Pull out part of placeholder and place above input field for mobile

Tags: html, jquery, css, input, placeholder

I received a request to include a 65-character placeholder in a text input field when viewed on desktop with two different styles. However, when viewed on tablet or mobile, part of the placeholder needs to be moved above the input field.

The placeholder should read this on desktop:
"Find guitar specialist. Enter your guitar make and model..."

On tablet and mobile, "Find guitar specialist" needs to be moved above the input field, leaving the placeholder to read, "Enter your guitar make and model..."

I managed to create the two styles for the placeholder, but am stuck with the best way to display the first portion of the placeholder above the field, WITHOUT duplicating the text. Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container test">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">

<div class="guitar-service-address">
    <span class="placeholder-location">Find guitar repair specialist. <span class="font-alt">Enter your guitar make and model...</span></span>
  <input id="input" size="78" type="text" />&nbsp;
</div>
<p class="help-block">What is this?</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.guitar-service-address>span.placeholder-location {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 8px;
  color: #686e74;
  cursor: auto;
  font: Helvetica 15px/20px bold;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
}

.guitar-service-address>span.placeholder-location>span.font-alt {
  color: #686e74;
  font-weight: normal;
}

 input {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #979797; 
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.help-block {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.test {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("span.placeholder-location + input").keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length) {
            $(this).prev('span.placeholder-location').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('span.placeholder-location').show();
        }
    });
    $("span.placeholder-location").click(function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

Here's a link to a Liveweave:
https://liveweave.com/1TtCbY

Comment: You might find a more general solution using pseudo elements rather than having to put what is essentially placeholder text into your document, though the 'Find guitar repair specialist' would probably sit more naturally as a label, especially if we consider accessibility. Is it OK to change the HTML a little?

Comment: I'm okay with changing up the HTML, but I don't see how ::placeholder will help. What adds a little bit of trickiness is that a) the placeholder is split into two different styles and b) a segment of the placeholder has to be displayed outside the input for tablet and mobile. If you can... let me know what you're thinking. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking of an after pseudo element to put in the second part.

Comment: The second part will always be there as a placeholder. It's the first part of the placeholder that will not be displayed on tablet and mobile.